# Hotkey to move a tab from one of two split editors to another?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I split my editor into two halves, left and right, and I wanna move a file that is opened in a tab from the left-hand side editor to the right one and vice versa.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>

Command names:

- `workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup` **View: Move Editor into Next Group**
- `workbench.action.moveEditorToPreviousGroup` **View: Move Editor into Previous Group**

Extra:

- `workbench.action.moveEditorToAboveGroup` **View: Move Editor into Above Group**
- `workbench.action.moveEditorToBelowGroup` **View: Move Editor into Below Group**
- `workbench.action.moveEditorToFirstGroup` **View: Move Editor into First Group**
- `workbench.action.moveEditorToLastGroup` **View: Move Editor into Last Group**

Comment: Wondering why my VSCode make a ding sound each time I move the tab from one pane to another...

Comment: On version 1.32.1 on Windows I see this: `Ctrl+Alt+.` for moving it to right and  `Ctrl+Alt+,` for moving it to the left.

Comment: I don't see this. At least not in the default mapping.

Comment: I think you're right, my bad. I must have re-mapped it and forgot about it.

Comment: On Ubuntu the default keybinding (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`→`/`←`) didn't work for me, so I rebinded `Ctrl` to `Super` and it worked

Comment: I use `Size Up`, the popular window manager. It conflicts with VSCode's shortcuts. Can change either one to work, though.

Comment: Where can I see this shortcut besides the default keybindings json? I copied the moveeditorprevious...next cmds to the keybindings json as a lookup. Should be a valid lookup and maybe the "best" one.

Comment: On Ubuntu ```Ctrl```+```Alt```(+```↑```/```↓```) is reserved for navigating through desktop workspaces. So as @dspacejs suggested, one should map at another shortcut.

Comment: This fixes the "error" sound issues - https://superuser.com/questions/1418419/macos-making-bell-sound-on-moving-line-down-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 2):

For those who are attempting this in a Windows Remote Desktop window it will not work. I struggled with this for quite some time before realizing that the Ctrl+Alt+</Arrow keys/> shortcut was not reaching my remote desktop session :(

I found the reason on stackExchange - https://superuser.com/questions/327866/remote-desktop-sending-ctrl-alt-left-arrow-ctrl-alt-right-arrow-to-the-remote-p

There are some workarounds that are provided in this thread, but none that I could use inside my company. My only solution is to re-map the command to a different shortcut that isn't being consumed by RDP.

Hope it helps someone!