# Hotkey to move a tab from one of two split editors to another in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, hotkeys

Basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018175/hotkey-to-move-a-tab-from-one-of-two-split-editors-to-another) but for Visual Studio: Say I split my editor into two halves, left and right, and I wanna move a file that is opened in a tab from the left-hand side editor to the right one and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **NO** default hotkeys but you can assign them in `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard`.

The commands are:

- `Window.MovetoNextTabGroup`
- `Window.MovetoPreviousTabGroup`

*Note:* If you set to the same hotkey to VS Code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>), it's occupied by another set of hotkeys. You need to remove them for it to work.

[image]